# Can list's iterator return a non-const reference?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm super new to C++. I need to write a Linked List class that uses `list`. I'm most of the way there, but I need a `[]` operator that returns the nth element in the list. I have this working in most cases, but in my test driver I need to compare two elements from different lists. (I.e. `l1[n]==l2[m]`). This gives the following compile error:

```
error: passing ‘const StrList {aka const TList<std::basic_string<char> >}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘T& TList<T>::operator[](int) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I think the problem here is that my return call from the iterator in the `[]` operator is returning a const reference. (The return call from the `[]` operator is `return(*iter);`, where `*iter` refers to the correct element.

Is there a way to return the reference to the iterator as a non-const reference, or is there some other way I should be going about this? I can post more code if it's necessary.

Comment: Sorry @Yuushi, I don't think I understand. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Whatever `TList` you're trying to get a reference to a non-const element from is marked `const`. The language doesn't let you get non-const stuff from const stuff without an explicit cast, and for good reason. If I have a const thing, I expect it not to change.

Comment: I didn't read the error clearly enough. Likely the problem is the opposite of what you describe: you're returning a non-const reference but you need a const reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's slightly hard to tell without code, but given the error, you likely need a `const` overload of `operator[]`:

```
template <typename T>
const T& operator[](std::size_t n) const
{
     ...
}
```